# Is it always true that $N_{(G,G)}(T_1) \subseteq N_G(T)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive linear algebraic group whose semisimple rank is $1$.  Then $H := (G,G)$ is a connected semisimple group of rank one.  Let $T_1$ be a maximal torus of $H$, and let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$ containing $T_1$.  Is it true that $$N_H(T_1) \subseteq N_G(T)$$ and that $$T_1 = N_H(T_1) \cap T?$$  If so, the inclusion $N_H(T_1) \subseteq N_G(T)$ would induce an isomorphism of Weyl groups $W(G,T) \cong W(H,T_1)$.

In the single example I have worked, this is the case:  Let $G = \textrm{GL}_2$, and $H = (G,G) = \textrm{SL}_2$.  Take $$T_1 = \{ \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0& x^{-1} \end{pmatrix} : x \in k^{\ast} \}$$ and $$T = \{ \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0& y \end{pmatrix} : x,y \in k^{\ast} \}$$ Set $n = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  And note that $n \in N_H(T_1) \setminus T_1$.  Since we know that $N_H(T_1)/T_1$ has order two, it follows that $$N_H(T_1) = T_1 \cup nT_1 $$ So in this case it's easy to check that $N_H(T_1) \subseteq N_G(T)$ and $T_1 = N_H(T_1) \cap T$.

Comment: One thing that might help me is the fact that $R(G)$, the radical of $G$, is the connected component of the center of $G$.  The radical is a subtorus of $T$ of codimension $1$, and it has finite intersection with $T_1$.  If $n \in N_H(T_1)$, then $$E = \{ t \in T : ntn^{-1} \in T \}$$ is a closed subgroup of $T$ containing $R(G)$.  So $E$ has dimension at least $\textrm{Dim } T - 1$.  Also, $E$ contains $T_1$, a one dimensional irreducible subvariety of $T$ which has finite intersection with $R(G)$.  Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's true?  Not sure if this is right.  If $R(G)$ is the radical, then the product map $R(G) \times T_1 \rightarrow T$ is a morphism of algebraic groups with kernel $R(G) \cap T_1$, which is finite.  The image is $R(G).T_1$, which is a closed, connected subgroup of $T$.  The dimension of the image is $$\textrm{Dim } R(G) \times T_1 - \textrm{Dim } R(G) \cap T_1 = \textrm{Dim } R(G) + \textrm{Dim } T_1 - 0 = \textrm{Dim } T$$ so $R(G)$ and $T_1$ generate $T$.  Any element of $N_G(T_1)$ normalizes $R(G)$ and $T_1$, so it must normalize $T$.

So this shows that $N_H(T_1) \subseteq N_G(T_1) \subseteq N_G(T)$.

Now $N_H(T_1) \cap T$ is a subgroup of $N_H(T_1)$ containing $T_1$. The quotient $N_H(T_1)/T_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so either $N_H(T_1) \cap T = T_1$ or $N_H(T_1) \cap T = N_H(T_1)$.

This last case can't happen.  If $N_H(T_1) \cap T = N_H(T_1)$, then $N_H(T_1) \subseteq T$.  Let $n \in N_H(T_1)$ but not in $T_1$.  Then we know that $n$ has the effect $ntn^{-1} = t^{-1}$ for all $t \in T_1$ (classification of automorphisms of the affine line).  But $n \in T$, so $ntn^{-1} = t$ for all $t \in T_1$, contradiction.

Comment: In fact this argument has nothing to do with semisimple rank 1; maximal tori in reductive groups are self-centralising, so $N_H(T_1) \cap T \subseteq N_H(T_1) \cap C_G(T_1) = C_H(T_1) = T_1$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.